# Can't place circular progress bar into the movie card and make it fit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, material-ui

Having trouble putting my react circular bar for movie rating into the bottom corner of the movie card. Also classes can't seem to work properly .I saw it on another website made with React and SCSS but I'm using Material-UI. It should look like this:

movie card

[image: 1]

This is the original code:

```
import React from "react";
import { CircularProgressbar, buildStyles } from "react-circular-progressbar";
import "react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css";

import "./style.scss";

const CircleRating = ({ rating }) => {
    return (
        <div className="circleRating">
            <CircularProgressbar
                value={rating}
                maxValue={10}
                text={rating}
                styles={buildStyles({
                    pathColor:
                        rating < 5 ? "red" : rating < 7 ? "orange" : "green",
                })}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default CircleRating;
```

```
.circleRating {
    background-color: var(--black);
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 2px;
    .CircularProgressbar-text {
        font-size: 34px;
        font-weight: 700;
        fill: var(--black);
    }
    .CircularProgressbar-trail {
        stroke: transparent;
    }
}
```

And this is my code:
CircularProgressbar.jsx:

```
import { CircularProgressbar, buildStyles } from "react-circular-progressbar";

import useStyles from "./styles";

const CircleRating = ({ rating }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.circleRating}>
      <CircularProgressbar
        className={classes.circularProgressbar_text}
        value={rating}
        maxValue={10}
        text={rating}
        styles={buildStyles({
          pathColor: rating < 5 ? "red" : rating < 7 ? "orange" : "green",
        })}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CircleRating;
```

styles:

```
import "react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

export default makeStyles(() => ({
  circleRating: {
    backgroundColor: "var(--black)",
    borderRadius: "50%",
    padding: "2px",
  },
  circularProgressbar_text: {
    fontSize: "16px",
    fontWeight: "700",
    fill: "var(--black)",
  },
  circularProgressbar_rail: {
    stroke: "transparent",
  },
}));
```

movie.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { Typography, Grid, Grow, Tooltip, Rating } from "@mui/material";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import CircleRating from "../CircleRating/CircleRating";

import useStyles from "./styles";

function Movie({ movie, i }) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3} xl={2} className={classes.movie}>
      <Grow in key={i} timeout={(i + 1) * 250}>
        <Link className={classes.links} to={`/movie/${movie.id}`}>
          <img
            src={
              movie.poster_path
                ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movie.poster_path}`
                : "https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300"
            }
            alt={movie.title}
            className={classes.image}
          />
          <Tooltip disableTouchListener title={`${movie.vote_average} / 10`}>
            <div>
              <CircleRating rating={movie.vote_average.toFixed(1)} />
            </div>
          </Tooltip>
          <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h5">
            {movie.title}
          </Typography>
        </Link>
      </Grow>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default Movie;
```

styles.js:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
  movie: {
    padding: "10px",
    position: "relative",
  },
  title: {
    color: theme.palette.text.primary,
    textOverflow: "ellipsis",
    width: "230px",
    overflow: "hidden",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    marginTop: "10px",
    marginBottom: 0,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  links: {
    alignItems: "center",
    fontWeight: "bolder",
    textDecoration: "none",
    position: "relative",
    display: "inline-block",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("xs")]: {
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
    },
    "&:hover": {
      cursor: "pointer",
    },
  },
  image: {
    borderRadius: "20px",
    height: "300px",
    marginBottom: "10px",
    "&:hover": {
      transform: "scale(1.05)",
    },
  },
}));
```

Comment: try to do this using the relative and absolute properties.
make parent and relative and that circle absolute

Answer (score 0):

The MUI docs for the latest version (v5.11.12) mention: *JSS itself is [no longer supported](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#jss-tss) in MUI.* So, I provided a possible solution that uses the **[sx prop](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/)** instead of *makeStyles* and *useStyles*. The styling objects in *styles.js* below are similar to those in your sample code. The solution replaces some of the components in your sample code with MUI alternatives that might be a better fit given their intended purpose (e.g. *Card* instead of *Link*). Some of the code below could have been less verbose. But, it is there to help you understand how the styling works and give you a head start to finding a solution.

@Syed Aman Ali had the right idea about positioning. The file *CircularProgressIndicator.jsx* uses *absolute* positioning for the CircularProgress indicator and the Box containing the rating label. Both of these components are contained in a parent Box that has *relative* positioning.

See this [live demo](https://kofeigen.srht.site/so/so-75707795) for the code below.

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MovieCard and CircularProgress test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scalable=1">
        <link rel="icon" href="data:;">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="testContainer" class="testContainer"></div>
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
        <noscript> Please enable javascript to view the site </noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

### index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Movie from './movie.jsx';

const container = document.getElementById( 'testContainer' );

ReactDOM.render(
    <Movie
        i={ 1 }
        movie={ {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Godzilla Strikes Back (2023)',
            poster_path: '',
            vote_average: 71.4
        } }
    />,
    container
);
```

### styles.js

```
/**
 * @file: styles.js.
 *
 * A few inline comments indicate changes to original styling.
 */
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme();

export default {
    movie: {
        position: 'relative',
        backgroundColor: 'black', // 'var(--black)'
        borderRadius: '4px', // '50%'
        padding: '10px', // edited
        width: '250px', // new
        overflow: 'hidden' // new
    },
    title: {
        paddingTop: '10px',
        color: theme.palette.common.white, // edited
        textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    image: {
        borderRadius: '20px',
        transition: 'transform .5s',
        '&:hover': {
            transform: 'scale(1.05)'
        }
    },
    circularProgressbar_text: {
        position: 'relative',
        top: '10px',
        fontSize: '16px',
        fontWeight: '700',
        color: 'black' // 'var(--black)'
    }
};
```

### movie.jsx

```
/**
 * @file: movie.jsx.
 */
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Grow from '@mui/material/Grow';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@mui/material/CardActionArea';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@mui/material/CardMedia';

import CircleRating from './CircularProgressIndicator.jsx';
import defaultImage from './image.jpg';

import classes from './styles.js';

function Movie( { movie, i } ) {

    // If using a router replace the window.location assignment with a call to add the new
    // location to the router.
    const navigateToTarget = () => {
        window.location = `/movie/${movie.id}`;
    }

    return (
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3} xl={2} sx={ classes.movie }>
            <Grow in key={i} timeout={(i + 1) * 250}>
                <Card>
                    <CardActionArea
                        disableRipple={ true }
                        onClick={ navigateToTarget }
                        sx={ { minHeight: 0, backgroundColor: 'black' } }
                    >
                        <div style={ { height: '300px', overflow: 'hidden' } }>
                            <CardMedia
                                component={ 'img' }
                                title={ movie.title }
                                alt={ movie.title }
                                image={ movie.poster_path
                                    ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movie.poster_path}`
                                    : defaultImage
                                }
                                sx={ classes.image }
                            />
                        </div>
                        <CardContent>
                            <Box sx={ { position: 'absolute', top: '275px' } }>
                                <CircleRating rating={ movie.vote_average } />
                            </Box>
                            <Typography
                                noWrap
                                variant='h5'
                                title={ movie.title }
                                sx={ classes.title }
                            >
                                { movie.title }
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                    </CardActionArea>
                </Card>
            </Grow>
        </Grid>
    );
}

export default Movie;
```

### CircularProgressIndicator.jsx

```
/**
 * @file: CircularProgressIndicator.jsx.
 */
import React from 'react';
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import styles from './styles.js';

/**
 * CircularProgress indicator with label.
 *
 * @see {@link https://mui.com/material-ui/react-progress/#circular-with-label}
 */
export default function CircularProgressWithLabel( props ) {
    const maxRating = 100;
    let decimals = props.rating % 10 == 0 ? 0 : 1; // Number of decimals to display.

    /**
     * Prop 'value' of the MUI CircularProgress component must be between 0 and 100.
     * @see {@link }https://mui.com/material-ui/api/circular-progress/#props}
     * @type {number}
     */
    let rating = Math.min( props.rating, maxRating );
    let base10Rating = rating / 10;

    /**
     * Label displayed inside the CircularProgress circle is between 0 and 10 with zero
     * or one decimal place.
     * @type {number}
     */
    let label = base10Rating.toFixed( decimals );

    return (
        <Box
            sx={ {
                display: 'flex',
                position: 'relative',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                width: '48px',
                height: '48px',
                borderRadius: '50%',
                backgroundColor: '#fff'
            } }
        >
            <Box
                sx={ {
                    display: 'flex',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center'
                } }
            >
                <Typography
                    component='div'
                    variant='caption'
                    color='text.secondary'
                    sx={ styles.circularProgressbar_text } 
                >
                    { label }
                </Typography>
            </Box>
            <CircularProgress
                value={ parseFloat( rating ) }
                size={ 42 }
                variant='determinate'
                sx={ {
                    [`&.MuiCircularProgress-root.MuiCircularProgress-determinate.MuiCircularProgress-colorPrimary`]: {
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: '3px',
                        left: '3px',
                        overflow: 'hidden',
                        zIndex: 1,
                        [`& .MuiCircularProgress-circle.MuiCircularProgress-circleDeterminate`]: {
                            stroke: ( theme ) => {
                                return parseFloat( label ) < 5
                                    ? 'red'
                                    : parseFloat( label ) < 7
                                        ? 'orange'
                                        : `${theme.palette.success.light}`;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } }
                { ...props }
            />
        </Box>
    );
}
```